academic/scholarly term for Interface belonging to class library(in a dll or jar file) that must be implemented by the client application code
Let's say one has a Financial Foreign Exchange Processor Class Library called ForeignXchangeProc and a client business application that uses said Class Library.
However, within the ForeignXchangeProc, there is an interface called IForeignXchangeProcSetupHelper which is an interface for setting up or configuring said ForeignXchangeProc instance for a particular client business application.
When the client business application uses the ForeignXchangeProc class library ( i.e. used as dll in .NET or a jar file in Java ), said client application must write an implementation class for the IForeignXchangeProcSetupHelper interface.
What is the academic/scholarly term for the IForeignXchangeProcSetupHelper interface in the Object Oriented Programming (OOP) field?  Would be something like “hook” or something?
